# LEFT JOIN returns incorrect result in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, left-join

I have two tables: A (525,968 records) and B (517,831 records). I want to generate a table with all the rows from A and the matched records from B. Both tables has column "id" and column "year". The combination of id and year in table A is unique, but not in table B. So I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT
 A.id,
 A.year,
 A.v1,
 B.x1,
 B.e1
FROM
A
LEFT JOIN B ON (A.id = B.id AND A.year = B.year);
```

I thought the result should contain the same total number of records in A, but it only returns about 517,950 records. I'm wondering what the possible cause may be.

Thanks!

Comment: The query should return all records of table `A`. Is this the whole query, or is there a `WHERE` clause as well?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I understand that this is an example, but postgres may hava an issues with capital letters in the table names.

Secondly, it may be a good idea to check how exactly you calculated 525,968 records. The thing is - if you use sime kind of client of database administration / queries - it may show you different / technical information about tables (there may be internal row counters in postgres that may actually differ from the number of records).

And finally to check yourself do something like

```
SELECT 
 count("A".id)
FROM 
 "A"
```